# Conflicto al subir y editar un campo de un fichero en Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Llevo días con este problema y por más que he probado todo lo que he leído, nada me funciona.

Al subir un fichero a una biblioteca de Sharepoint, intento rellenar uno de sus metadatos mediante un desarrollo. Al hacerlo obtengo un error de conflicto de guardado del fichero. El código es el siguiente:

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdated(properties);

    if (properties.List.Title.Equals("Process"))
    {
        EventFiringEnabled = false;

        string numExped = "0001";
        properties.ListItem["ExpedNumber"] = numExped;
        properties.ListItem.Update();

        EventFiringEnabled = true;
    }       
}
```

He probado mil cosas, desde poner SystemUpdate en lugar de Update. Ponerle también un *false* como parámetro al Update. Quitar y poner los EventFiringEnabled. Instanciar un *item* en lugar de usar el propio *properties.ListItem*.

Pero nada, cuando introduzco los metadatos y pulso proteger, siempre obtengo este error:

[image: Conflicto al guardar]

El fichero se guarda pero queda sin proteger.
¿Alguien puede decirme que estoy haciendo mal? Gracias, un saludo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Y si lo intentas así:

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdated(properties);

    using (DisabledEventsScope scope = new DisabledEventsScope())
    {
        if (properties.List.Title.Equals("Process"))
        {
            EventFiringEnabled = false;

            string numExped = "0001";
            properties.ListItem["ExpedNumber"] = numExped;
            properties.ListItem.Update();

            EventFiringEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```